# json parsing with listview?

Tags: android, json

I have seen and other relevant posts but I can't understand which place of code I must change.If someone has some idea what's this I should change to code, thanks. The following is the code of MainActivity and xmls etc

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.dell.json;

import android.app.ListActivity;
....
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "{\n" +
            "    \"contacts\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"c200\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"Ravi Tamada\",\n" +
            "                \"email\": \"ravi@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\n" +
            "                \"gender\" : \"male\",\n" +
            "                \"phone\": {\n" +
            "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"c201\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\",\n" +
            "                \"email\": \"johnny_depp@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\n" +
            "                \"gender\" : \"male\",\n" +
            "                \"phone\": {\n" +
            "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"c202\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"Leonardo Dicaprio\",\n" +
            "                \"email\": \"leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\n" +
            "                \"gender\" : \"male\",\n" +
            "                \"phone\": {\n" +
            "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"c203\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"John Wayne\",\n" +
            "                \"email\": \"john_wayne@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\n" +
            "                \"gender\" : \"male\",\n" +
            "                \"phone\": {\n" +
            "                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\n" +
            "                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "        },\n";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            ListView lv = getListView();

            // Listview on item click listener
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem
                            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                                    .getText().toString();
                            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                                    .getText().toString();
                            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                                    .getText().toString();

                            // Starting single contact activity
                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    SingleContactActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                            startActivity(in);

                    }
            });

            // Calling async task to get json
            new GetContacts().execute();
    }

        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         * */
        private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        // Showing progress dialog
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        pDialog.show();

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        // Creating service handler class instance
                        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                        // Making a request to url and getting response
                        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

                        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                        if (jsonStr != null) {
                                try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                                        // Getting JSON Array node
                                        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                                        // looping through All Contacts
                                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                                                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                                                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                                                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                                                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                                                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                                                // Phone node is JSON Object
                                                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                                                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                                                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                                                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                                                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                                                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                                                contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                                                contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                                                contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                                                // adding contact to contact list
                                                contactList.add(contact);
                                        }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        } else {
                                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                        }

                        return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        // Dismiss the progress dialog
                        if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                                TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                                R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
        }
}
```

And the following is the ERRORS:

```
    10-06 15:04:27.627 19502-19502/? D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41f56e98
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out: httpget:{
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:     "contacts": [
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:         {
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "id": "c200",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "name": "Ravi Tamada",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "gender" : "male",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "phone": {
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "home": "00 000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "office": "00 000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 }
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:         },
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:         {
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "id": "c201",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "name": "Johnny Depp",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "gender" : "male",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 "phone": {
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "home": "00 000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                     "office": "00 000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:                 }
    10-06 15:04:27.650 19502-19522/? I/System.out:         },
   ....
    10-06 15:04:27.651 19502-19522/? I/System.out:         },
    10-06 15:04:27.658 19502-19522/? D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
    10-06 15:04:27.658 19502-19522/? D/dalvikvm: create new thread
    10-06 15:04:27.659 19502-19522/? D/dalvikvm: new thread created
    10-06 15:04:27.659 19502-19522/? D/dalvikvm: update thread list
    10-06 15:04:27.659 19502-19524/? D/dalvikvm: threadid=12: interp stack at 0x6143d000
    10-06 15:04:27.660 19502-19524/? D/dalvikvm: threadid=12: created from interp
    10-06 15:04:27.667 19502-19522/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: {
    10-06 15:04:27.668 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20"contacts":%20[
    10-06 15:04:27.668 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.669 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"id":%20"c200",
    10-06 15:04:27.669 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"name":%20"Ravi%20Tamada",
    10-06 15:04:27.669 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"email":%20"ravi@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.669 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"address":%20"xx-xx-xxxx,x%20-%20street,%20x%20-%20country",
    10-06 15:04:27.669 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"gender"%20:%20"male",
    10-06 15:04:27.670 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"phone":%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.670 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"mobile":%20"+91%200000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.670 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"home":%20"00%20000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.671 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"office":%20"00%20000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.671 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}
   ...
    10-06 15:04:27.674 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"email":%20"leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"address":%20"xx-xx-xxxx,x%20-%20street,%20x%20-%20country",
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"gender"%20:%20"male",
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"phone":%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"mobile":%20"+91%200000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"home":%20"00%20000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.675 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"office":%20"00%20000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.678 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}
    10-06 15:04:27.678 19502-19522/? W/System.err: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20},
    10-06 15:04:27.683 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:730)
    10-06 15:04:27.684 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:83)
    10-06 15:04:27.684 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.json.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:68)
    10-06 15:04:27.685 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.json.ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.java:34)
    10-06 15:04:27.685 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at com.example.dell.json.MainActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:263)
    10-06 15:04:27.687 19502-19522/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.dell.json, PID: 19502
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: {
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20"contacts":%20[
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"id":%20"c200",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"name":%20"Ravi%20Tamada",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"email":%20"ravi@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"address":%20"xx-xx-xxxx,x%20-%20street,%20x%20-%20country",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"gender"%20:%20"male",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"phone":%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"mobile":%20"+91%200000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"home":%20"00%20000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"office":%20"00%20000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}
  ...
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"mobile":%20"+91%200000000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"home":%20"00%20000000",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"office":%20"00%20000000"
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20},
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"id":%20"c202",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"name":%20"Leonardo%20Dicaprio",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"email":%20"leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"address":%20"xx-xx-xxxx,x%20-%20street,%20x%20-%20country",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"gender"%20:%20"male",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20},
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20{
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"id":%20"c203",
    10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime: %20%20%20%20
    10-06 15:04:27.691 19502-19502/? E/: appName=com.example.dell.json, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
    10-06 15:04:27.691 19502-19502/? E/: 0
    10-06 15:04:27.691 19502-19502/? E/: appName=com.example.dell.json, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
    10-06 15:04:27.691 19502-19502/? E/: 0
    10-06 15:04:27.696 19502-19502/? D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x5d088eb0) (w:528, h:144, f:1)
    10-06 15:04:27.697 19502-19502/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
    10-06 15:04:27.697 19502-19502/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
    10-06 15:04:27.697 19502-19502/? I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
    10-06 15:04:27.699 19502-19502/? D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x5d088eb0) (w:528 h:144 f:1)
    10-06 15:04:27.700 19502-19502/? D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x5d088eb0) (w:528, h:144, f:1)
    10-06 15:04:27.703 19502-19522/? W/Process: killProcess [19502]
    10-06 15:04:27.703 19502-19502/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    10-06 15:04:27.704 19502-19522/? W/System.err: java.lang.Throwable
    10-06 15:04:27.705 19502-19502/? D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x619cf8e0) (w:768, h:768, f:1)
    10-06 15:04:27.708 19502-19502/? D/OpenGLRenderer: setViewport 513x144 <0x619cd6d8>
    10-06 15:04:27.715 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:957)
    10-06 15:04:27.717 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:94)
    10-06 15:04:27.717 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    10-06 15:04:27.717 19502-19522/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
    10-06 15:04:27.717 19502-19522/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19502 SIG: 9
```

Comment: from your log `10-06 15:04:27.690 19502-19522/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: `

Answer (score 0):

At the line:

```
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
```

makeServiceCall() first param seems to be expecting a url string since the stack trace shows:

```
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:730)
```

Seems like you are passing the json string when you should pass the url containing the json.

Why dont you change it to:

```
String jsonStr = url;
```

Hope this helps.